# Simulate a click event

Tags: javascript, events

Simulate a click event in html. But it pop a pop-up window.
How to solve this problem. Is there anybody know this problem?
Please help me.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementById('click');
    window.onload = function(){
        a.click();
    }
</script>
<a href="mydomian" id=clck">
</html>
```

Comment: What is the function for the onclick of `click` element? Can you show some more code

Comment: $(function() { $('#click').click(); });`

Comment: Your ID is wrong. change it to `click`.

Comment: And when you define `var a = ...` your element does not exist. So it will be empty. Also, your HTML is invalid (you never closed the `a` tag)

Comment: Yeah, Maybe I should format the codes. But it pop a pop-up window. I dont know that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like This:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('clck');
    a.addEventListener("click",function(){
      alert("Clicked.");
    });
}
</script>
<a href="mydomian" id=clck">
</html>
```